# How to access environment variable from zip in Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipeline:

```
environment {
    OUTPUT_FILE = 'OutputFile.zip'
}

stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            // Build my app
            zip archive: true, dir: 'zip', glob: '', zipFile: '${env.OUTPUT_FILE}'    
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the `OUTPUT_FILE` environment variable on the `zip` task, but it seems like the value is not resolved properly.

I have tried:

```
zip archive: true, dir: 'zip', glob: '', zipFile: '${OUTPUT_FILE}'
zip archive: true, dir: 'zip', glob: '', zipFile: '${env.OUTPUT_FILE}'
zip archive: true, dir: 'zip', glob: '', zipFile: '$OUTPUT_FILE'
```

None of them work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use incorrect syntax - in all your examples you use plain (and exact) string. However, in this case, you don't need to put `env.OUTPUT_FILE` inside any quotes, so the correct syntax is just:

```
zip archive: true, dir: 'zip', glob: '', zipFile: env.OUTPUT_FILE
```

or even

```
zip archive: true, dir: 'zip', glob: '', zipFile: OUTPUT_FILE
```

One thing worth mentioning. If you ever find yourself in a situation where you need to create a string using interpolation, then use double quotes. For instance, if you would like to echo the ZIP file name to console with some additional comment, then the following syntax would do the trick:

```
echo "The name of ZIP file is ${env.OUTPUT_FILE}"
```

Single quotes in Groovy are Java's `String` equivalent and they don't support variable interpolation.

Comment: Thanks for this- I'm not up to speed with Groovy and this was a good tip